# How do I change this code so it updates the current user instead of creating a new one?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I change this so it updates the current users details rather than creating a new user instead?

```
          Userdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
          Userdatabaseref = Userdatabase.getReference().child("Threads 
           Users");            


          DatabaseReference CurrentUser = Userdatabaseref.child("Threads 
          Users");

            Map<String, String> userdata = new HashMap<>();

            userdata.put("userfirstname", Fname);
            userdata.put("userlastname", Sname);
            userdata.put("userdateofbirth", DOB);
            userdata.put("useraddress", Add);
            userdata.put("userpostcode", Ptd);
            userdata.put("usercardnumber", Cnumber);
            userdata.put("usercardexpirydate", Cdate);
            userdata.put("userccvnumber ", CCV);

            CurrentUser.setValue(userdata);
        }
    });
```

Comment: whats your flow? do you understand why a NEW user is being created?

Comment: Try using CurrentUser.updateChildValues

Comment: i do not know why a new user is being created and Currentuser.updatechildValues is not an option

Comment: have updated with the called values

Comment: try this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `updateChildren` for this:

```
Userdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
Userdatabaseref = Userdatabase.getReference().child("Threads 
           Users");            
DatabaseReference CurrentUser = Userdatabaseref.child("Threads 
          Users").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
Map<String, Object> userdata = new HashMap<>();
userdata.put("userfirstname", Fname);
userdata.put("userlastname", Sname);
userdata.put("userdateofbirth", DOB);
userdata.put("useraddress", Add);
userdata.put("userpostcode", Ptd);
userdata.put("usercardnumber", Cnumber);
userdata.put("usercardexpirydate", Cdate);
userdata.put("userccvnumber ", CCV);

CurrentUser.updateChildren(userdata);
```

Comment: i have an error message showing that CurrentUser.updateChildren(userdata); cannot be applied to a database reference how do i remedy this

Comment: Change from Map<String, String> userdata = new HashMap<>(); to Map<String, Object> userdata = new HashMap<>();

Comment: This is just creating a new user  ? any idea why ?

Comment: the node you're trying to update has to have all the attributes in the map, otherwise it will just add a new one

Comment: any luck @Daniel?

Comment: i am still amending my code so that it will change all the fields